# How did Gibbons survive the blast in XXX: The Return of Xander Cage?

Tags: plot-explanation, xxx-return-of-xander-cage

It is shown that in a blast caused by a crashing  satellite Gibbons and Junior Neymar get killed.

But at the end it is shown that both are still alive.

How is it possible to survive such a blast?

Comment: [The team attends Gibbons' funeral, where Xander is approached by Gibbons himself, **who faked his death**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXx:_Return_of_Xander_Cage)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question that how it is logically possible?

Comment: @Sonevol Think of it like a magician who tosses a piece of cloth and disappears. There might be a secret compartment in which he hid himself when that blast occurred.

Comment: @Sonevol answer it, we don't know

Comment: Logic &/or physics does not always apply in movies...especially xXx movies.

Comment: @Paulie_D first movie was not that illogical. But the third one seems to be written by a person who is under drugs.

Comment: Based on discussion here, it sounds like the answer to the question posed is "we don't know, the movie didn't explain it."  Asking for *theories* about how it *might've been done* seems like "primarily opinion-based" to me.

Comment: Just to be clear, we're asking about "logically possible" for one of the "XXX" action movies? Isn't that an exercise in futility and guaranteed frustration? It would kind of be like asking why they don't run out of ammo in a John Woo film.

Comment: @Sonevol: "But the third one seems to be written by a person who is under drugs." Your own statement implies that there is no plot logic to be found. That makes it hard to provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the satellite crashing in this pic, and makes us conclude that Gibbons dies there.

[image]

Then we see only flames after the crash.

We didn't see him die - we just saw him in the building when the explosion happened nearby. But the end scene states that Gibbons and Neymer were alive all the time.

> Presumably, Gibbons and Neymar made it out the back door just in time.

Afterwards, he stayed hidden because he wanted to wait and see if and why someone wanted him dead.

Comment: it would be better if they explained us, how he escaped. (At the end of the movie for example)